# Preposition for use of "proxy" as an adjective

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I would like to say that some thing A is used as a proxy for another thing B.
How would I express this with "proxy" as an adjective?

To me,

> A is proxy to B and less expensive.

sounds more natural than

> A is proxy for B and less expensive.

Are *to* and *for* both fine, is only one of them correct, or is neither correct?

Thanks

Comment: Why should you be bothering yourself with the preposition in the first place? Why not simply say _A is B's proxy_?

Comment: @user405662 Because this is part of a technical sentence that very accurately expresses something I want to say (conditional on one of the above being correct).

Comment: 'Instead of' looks more natural here. A proxy carries the idea of a temporary stand-in.

Comment: Neither is correct; *proxy* is not an adjective — it's a noun. And I don't think you mean *proxy* at all. Did you look it up?

Comment: @TinfoilHat I actually looked up if proxy was an adjective and wiktionary said yes – are they incorrect? And yeah, I meant proxy, I think; I just need an adjective that says that something is a model/placeholder for something else.

Comment: @Ramen - You should add that reference to your question -- that's very important.  It's part of what is called "show your research" and you should do that for your question to be well posed.  That's the sort of thing that makes a question interesting for volunteer responders.  Also, please include the actual sentence in the actual context.  The example you gave doesn't need the word "proxy" but apparently the actual sentence and scientific context you have does need this word -- so we need to see it, please.

Answer (score 1):

> A is a proxy for B and less expensive.

> The interest rate **is a proxy for** the cost of credit, and the real
> effective exchange rate **is a proxy for** relative prices. [Lawrence
> Pelzer, *New Developments in Macroeconomics Research*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_Developments_in_Macroeconomics_Resea/ddqutnEu1l4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22is%20a%20proxy%20for%22&pg=PA52&printsec=frontcover) (2006)

> If social class **is a proxy for** how we live, each SES indicator
> **is a proxy for** a somewhat different dimension of that life. [Proceedings of the 1993 Public Health Conference on Records and
> Statistics; *Toward the Year 2000*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Proceedings_of_the_Public_Health_Confere/pSGz401HRWwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22is%20a%20proxy%20for%22&pg=PA184&printsec=frontcover)

---

*Proxy* is noun (and a verb), but you can use it attributively as a modifier.

> A common solution is to do a **proxy vote**, which means that you
> assign another person to vote in your place. [Jennifer Reuting;
> *Limited Liability Companies For Dummies*](http://Limited_Liability_Companies_For_Dummies) (2008)

> For example, according to officials at one company we interviewed, if
> a **proxy vote** is to be cast not in accordance with the plan's
> guidelines, then the vote is decided by the plan's proxy committee ...
> [GAO; *Pension Plans*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pension_plans_additional_transparency_an/3rtgke4_TmwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22proxy%20vote%22&pg=PA21&printsec=frontcover)

> Charles Bridges had sued the stockholder committee for libel,
> complaining that the **proxy letter** had falsely charged that his
> management was incompetent and that the company had deceived
> shareholders about the company's finances. [Diana B. Henriques; *The
> White Sharks of Wall Street*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_White_Sharks_of_Wall_Street/8jK6eHuSa84C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22proxy%20letter%22&pg=PT218&printsec=frontcover) (2001)

> On a practical note, there are 83 observations for which the time
> between the board date and the **proxy date** exceeds 60 days, and 1
> observation with a 290 days difference between the board and **proxy
> dates**. [J. Choi and S. Dow; *Institutional Approach to Global
> Corporate Governance*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Institutional_Approach_to_Global_Corpora/WRkUsgPvnq4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22proxy%20date%22&pg=PA197&printsec=frontcover) (2008)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you want your answer to imply that the usage with *for* and *to* as in my question are incorrect?

Comment: I would wait a for a lawyer to chime in, but I suggest "A is **a** proxy **for** B and less expensive"--***to*** sounds wrong and you need an article--*a proxy*. Note that *proxy* is still a noun in your example. You can't use it like you would "proximal to." *Proxy* derives from *procuracy*.

Comment: Thanks, your last comment helped me a lot.

Comment: [_Proxy fights_](https://www.google.com/search?q=Proxy+fight) have occurred frequently in the investment community. That's a pretty standard noun compound.

Comment: @JohnLawler Lexico has [*proxy war*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/proxy_war), a real war, as well.